# How to export SLO's from my GCP organization in Prometheus?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I wanted to use the SLO's metrics created by me on my Google Cloud Project on Grafana, my collector here are Prometheus and some direct connectors to Bigquery and Cloud Monitoring that Grafana offers but wasn't able to find something useful regarding the same. It would be appreciated if someone could tell me a way to get the SLO metrics on Prometheus or some way of getting my SLO's on Grafana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. create a Grafana dashboard to visualize metrics; Prometheus plugin is included in Grafana.

- Enable Prometheus plugin in Grafana.
- Login into Grafana where the server is running.
- In side meny, select configuration>Data sources and select Add data source.
- Name your data source and select Prometheus as data source Type.
- Enter the url where the Prometheus server is running and select the server and save and Test it.

B.
To create Grafana dashboard using Prometheus data source.

- Log into the Grafana instance and from the side menu you need to select Create> Import.
- Upload.json file and select preconfigured Grafana dashboard and enter a name for the dashboard and select import.

For prerequisites please check this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/monitoring/doc/monitoring/metricsCollector/mcExportMetricsManually.html).

Comment: Please share the status of your issue; if solved and given solution is useful; upvote/accept so, that it will be useful for other community members.